# STATA: Create Dataset from Contingency Tables for Statistical Interaction

Tags: dataset, stata, odds-ratio

I have three contingency tables for a case-control study:

1. the crude 2x2 table with exposure and outcome:

   ```
   |   | D+ | D-|
   | --| -- | --|
   |E+ | 10 | 20|
   |E- | 30 | 40|
   ```
2. 2x2 table with covariate, C= 0

   ```
   |   | D+ | D-|
   |---|----|---|
   |E+ | 3  | 10|
   |E- | 15 | 25|
   ```
3. 2x2 table with covariate, C = 1

   ```
   |   | D+ | D-|
   | --| -- | --|
   |E+ | 7  | 10|
   |E- | 15 | 15|
   ```

How can I create a dataframe in STATA with these values for the variables E, D, and C? I need to calculate the MH odds ratio.

I tried using the "cci" command but it doesn't work with multiple tables